# How do I secure pages and related media files?

Tags: 7, security

I would like to password protect Drupal pages (solved) and media files related to these pages (solved, but not optimally).  Currently the Drupal pages are secured via Drupal and the media files via htaccess.  The problem with this is the users then have to authenticate twice to get to the media content.  I've been told that the way to solve this is to create a role and restrict access to both Drupal pages and media using [Private files download permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/private_files_download_permission) module.

I'm quite new to Drupal and am wondering if this is the *normal* way that people solve this problem; or is another method better/more common/etc..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Secure Site](https://www.drupal.org/project/securesite) for this.

> This module allows you to authenticate users with a browser-based password (HTTP Auth). You can restrict access to the site by role and choose to secure restricted pages or the entire site. This means the site will be inaccessible to search engines and other crawlers, but you can still allow access to certain users.